# Error in swift'Block' does not have a member named 'colorawValue'

Tags: swift

I am getting 3 errors in swift because of 'Blockcolor'
Here is all the code

```
import SpriteKit

let NumberOfColors: UInt32 = 6

enum BlockColor: Int, Printable {

    case Blue = 0, Orange, Purple, Red, Teal, Yellow

    var spriteName: String {
    switch self {
    case .Blue:
        return "blue"
    case .Orange:
        return "orange"
    case .Purple:
        return "purple"
    case .Red:
        return "red"
    case .Teal:
        return "teal"
    case .Yellow:
        return "yellow"
        }
    }

    var description: String {
    return self.spriteName
    }

    static func random() -> BlockColor {
        return BlockColor(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(NumberOfColors)))!
    }
}

class Block: Hashable, Printable {
    // Constants
    let color: BlockColor

    // Variables
    var column: Int
    var row: Int

    // Lazy loading
    var sprite: SKSpriteNode?

    var spriteName: String {
    return color.description
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
    return self.column ^ self.row
    }

    var description: String {
    return "\(color) (\(column), \(row))"
    }

    init(column:Int, row:Int, color:BlockColor) {
        self.column = column
        self.row = row
        self.color = color
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool {
    return lhs.column == rhs.column && lhs.row == rhs.row && lhs.BlockColor.rawValue == rhs.colorawValue()
}
```

Comment: There are some typos in your last function. `lhs.BlockColor.rawValue == rhs.colorawValue()` should be `lhs.color.rawValue == rhs.color.rawValue`. – After fixing that, your code compiles in my test project.

Comment: Did you search for `colorawValue` in your code after reading the compiler error message? – Btw, this is quite similar to your previous question, where you wrote `orientatiorawValue()` instead of `orientation.rawValue`. And don't forget to accept the answer to your last question if it helped!